# Using Express with NodeJS running with PM2: issues with POST res sending to ARC

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to writing a server with Express + NodeJS, and I've already run into a problem. I'm trying to create a mockup API endpoint - /api/login - and so far I have been unable to get data back when I send a POST request (through ARC).

My code looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => 
{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    );
    next();
});

app.post('/api/login', async (req, res, next) => 
{
  // req.body = { email : String, password : String }
  // res.text = { firstName : String, lastName : String, error : String }

    let err = '';
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    let fn = '';
    let ln = '';

    if ( email === 'stacey@email.com' && password === 'Test' )
    {
        fn = 'Stacey';
        ln = 'Dale';
    } else {
        err = 'Invalid user name/password';
    }

    let response = { firstName : fn, lastName : ln, error : err};
    console.log(response);
    res.status(200).json(response);
});

app.listen(5000);
```

After starting it with pm2, and opening the logs, I try to send a request with ARC:

Method: POST

Request URL: http://localhost:5000/api/login

Body Content Type: application/json

Body:

```json
{
"email" : "stacey@email.com",
"password" : "Test"
}
```

I see the `console.log(response)` looks like

```
0|server  | { firstName: 'Stacey', lastName: 'Dale', error: '' }
```

which is what I would expect. However, nothing ever returns to ARC. I have also tried only returning a status of 200, but to no avail.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I would say, first try removing the cors part, just to reduce complexity

Comment: But wouldn't this line make it still work with cors? 
res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );

Comment: sorry, what I'm suggesting first is to remove piece by piece until you make it work, then the last piece you removed was the one with the conflict :)
once you identify it, we can work on fixing it